# Vaadin 23 Grid with details - stretch instead scroll

Tags: vaadin, vaadin23

Is it possible to set up a Vaadin Grid with details (like in the Item Details example https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/grid) to stretch instead of displaying a scroll? I need to let the Grid grow as much as it needs to. Please tell me how to implement it.

P.S

I may only disable the visual scroll with `grid.setVerticalScrollingEnabled(false);` but it doesn't help with what I'm looking for. I also need to stretch the grid to avoid the grid scrolling at all. I'd like to use the entire page scrolling instead of grid personal scrolling.

Comment: What do you mean with stretch?

Comment: Grid should expand its height as much as needed to show the content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a flag you can set

> **setAllRowsVisible**
>
> public void setAllRowsVisible​(boolean
> allRowsVisible) If true, the grid's height is defined by its rows. All
> items are fetched from the DataProvider, and the Grid shows no
> vertical scroll bar.
>
> Note: setAllRowsVisible disables the grid's virtual scrolling so that
> all the rows are rendered in the DOM at once. If the grid has a large
> number of items, using the feature is discouraged to avoid performance
> issues.
>
> Parameters:
>
> allRowsVisible - true to make Grid compute its height by the number of
> rows, false for the default behavior